# What is the intrinsic metric of spheres?

Tags: metric-spaces, angle, spheres, geodesic

I'm currently confused about the intrinsic metric of spheres. Is it equivalent to the angular distance, the geodesic distance, or the great-circle distance? Are these metrics all defined as
$$
d(x, y)=\arccos{(x^{\top}y)}
$$
for $x, y$ on a unit sphere $\mathcal{S}^{p-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{p}$?

And for arbitrary $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^{p}$, can these metrics be represented as
$$
d(x, y)=\arccos{\left(\frac{x^{\top}y}{\|x\|\|y\|}\right)}?
$$

Comment: The intrinsic metric is the one obtained by integrating the Riemannian metric of constant curvature?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric) what you mean by "intrinsic metric"?

Comment: Actually I encounter this term in the second page of [Strong Negative Type in Spheres](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.02863.pdf) and I am uncertain what it means. If its meaning is indeed the "intrinsic metric" as @robjohn said, is it equivalent to those distances I mentioned above?

Comment: In a sense they do mean the arclength between two points. But when they say "metric" here, they mean "Riemannian metric", not the distance function you are asking about. "Intrinsic" is a poor choice of wording, as intrinsic has a specific meaning in differential geometry that is not met by this metric. "Canonical" would have been a better choice. But that canonical Riemannian metric does indeed correspond to the distance function giving minimum arclength along the sphere between two points.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So what you mean is when they say "intrinsic metric", they actually mean “canonical Riemannian metric", and this metric happens to be the distance function I write above when the space is a sphere, but it is not necessarily that case for other spaces. Do I understand it right?

Comment: A Reimannian metric is not the same thing as a distance function metric such as $d(x,y)$. The Riemannian metric is instead an inner product on the tangent bundle of a manifold. You calculate the length of a smooth curve by integrating the norm of the curves derivative. You can then obtain a distance function-metric by taking the minimum length over all curves connecting the two points. The distance function so generated by the canonical Riemannian metric on $S^n$ is the arclength metric you give.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: If we defined d(x,y) on the 2-sphere as the length of the shortest arc between x,y  within a great circle joining them, would such d(x,y) be a ( distance) metric? Other than the output not being a Real number and having a " triangle equality" rather than inequality,  it seems to satisfy all axioms.

Comment: @MSIS - A "Reimannian metric" is a smooth map from each point on a manifold to an inner product on the tangent space to the manifold at that point. This what I was referring to. Though still called "metric", this is a different beast than a binary map on a set into the non-negative real numbers that satisfies the triangle inequality. As I mentioned, you can use the Riemannian metric to define the other sort of metric. Which is what you describe. But my point is that certain things that were being said in the link refer to the Riemannian metric, not the distance function metric.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Thanks, I'm aware of that, just curious as to whether minimal arc length between two points on a (say) 2-sphere, is a metric in the distance sense.

Comment: @MSIS - As I've mentioned twice before in these comments: "**you can use the Riemannian metric to define the other sort of metric. Which is what you describe.**".